# Django - jQuery datatables stuck on loading

Tags: jquery, json, django, datatables

Sorry I am pretty new to Django and trying to laod a jQuery datatables with some data coming back from the server. the json coming back is in a good format. However, the data is not loading in the table and I get the following error in the firebug console:

```
TypeError: aData is undefined
for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) {
```

Additionally, I tried to play around with the `sAjaxDataProp` option to adjust the default behavior of `aaData` but I couldn't figure what it should be set to. Anyways below is the code for everything

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rfctable').dataTable({
        "sAjaxDataProp": '', // I don't know if I need this or how to deal with it
        "ajax": 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
        "columns": [
            { "fields": "rfc_number"},
            { "fields": "rfc_title"},
            { "fields": "rfc_question"},
        ]

    });
});
```

html:

```
<table id="rfctable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rfc Number</th>
        <th>RFC title</th>
        <th>RFC Questions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

json coming back from the url:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "rfc.rfcdocument",
        "fields": {
            "rfc_title": "123123123123",
            "rfc_answer_reviewed_by": 1,
            "rfc_required_fcd": true,
            "rfc_drawing_detail_number": "123",
            "rfc_required_sketch": true,
            "rfc_answer_authorized_by": 1,
            "rfc_issued_by": 1,
            "rfc_answer_issued_date": null,
            "rfc_specification_section": "34-5",
            "rfc_answered_date_architect": null,
            "rfc_question": "Salam baba?",
            "rfc_issued_date": null,
            "rfc_answer": "salama back!",
            "rfc_project": 1,
            "rfc_required_fls_review": true,
            "rfc_drawing_page_number": "54",
            "rfc_issued_to": 1
        }
    }
]
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is looking for the data to be in the property of `aaData` of the response from the server. Since the server is returning a list of objects, it's says it's undefined when it tries to access it.

You can't be using an empty string for `sAjaxDataProp`. You can read up more on what you should be returning from the server here: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side.

Change your jQuery part to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rfctable').dataTable({
        "sAjaxDataProp": 'data',
        "ajax": 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
        "columns": [
            { "fields": "rfc_number"},
            { "fields": "rfc_title"},
            { "fields": "rfc_question"},
        ]

    });
});
```

Change the response from the server to be:

```
{"data": [
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "rfc.rfcdocument",
        "fields": {
            "rfc_title": "123123123123",
            "rfc_answer_reviewed_by": 1,
            "rfc_required_fcd": true,
            "rfc_drawing_detail_number": "123",
            "rfc_required_sketch": true,
            "rfc_answer_authorized_by": 1,
            "rfc_issued_by": 1,
            "rfc_answer_issued_date": null,
            "rfc_specification_section": "34-5",
            "rfc_answered_date_architect": null,
            "rfc_question": "Salam baba?",
            "rfc_issued_date": null,
            "rfc_answer": "salama back!",
            "rfc_project": 1,
            "rfc_required_fls_review": true,
            "rfc_drawing_page_number": "54",
            "rfc_issued_to": 1
        }
    }
]}
```

You should also be returning `iTotalRecords`, `iTotalDisplayRecords`, and `sEcho` in the response.

Comment: This works for me. I'm using laravel though. I just added the `data` key. So, `return json_encode(['data' => $users]);`